# JFileChooser causes UnsatisfiedLinkError when showing dialog

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I have a method for opening a *JFileChooser* and selecting a File. When calling the *showOpenDialog* method I get an exception, but even so the Dialog opens, I can select a File, and move on with the program (though unless I call *System.exit(0)* at the end the JVM will not stop running).

```
public static File selectFile() {
    JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser(Paths.get("").toAbsolutePath().toFile());
    if(fc.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) { //Exception on This Line!!
        return fc.getSelectedFile();
    } else return null;
}
```

The exception loks like this:

```
Exception in thread "EventQueueMonitor-ComponentEvtDispatch" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no EnJavaJni in java.library.path
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
  at com.encentuate.JNICall.<clinit>(JNICall.java:67)
  at com.encentuate.EncentuateAWTHook.guiInitialized(EncentuateAWTHook.java:41)
  at com.sun.java.accessibility.util.EventQueueMonitor.maybeNotifyAssistiveTechnologies(EventQueueMonitor.java:228)
  at com.sun.java.accessibility.util.ComponentEvtDispatchThread.run(EventQueueMonitor.java:631)
```

I don't quite understad what the issue is. From what I can find through Google it has something to do with the method calling a native function that can't be found, but it does still work as "intended" other than throwing the Exception.

Any clues as to the issue?

EDIT: The main problem I have is that the program will not stop executing even when it is done. If that can be solved it's not a huge problem if it keeps printing out the exception message

Comment: possibly you have missing `libattach.dll` or `libattach.so`

Comment: Possible, but I have never had the issue before on other computers. It shouldn't require anything other than a Standard File Chooser which should be available on the System (otherwise, how could I even select where to save a file I download)

Answer (score 0):

this piece of code seem to work to me. Can I ask where are you calling it from? What operating system are you on?

Comment: Windows 10. I am running the program with Eclipse

Comment: @Arvind I cannot post a comment since "My rep is not 50", if there is any other way to ask, please let me know.

Comment: well, certainly others might ask OP the same question in comments